# Connection refused error when creating Http server using dart

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-html

I have created a server using a Plane dart and trying to listen to the response using HTTP get. I can access the response when I ping the I/P in browser but when trying to access in a demo app i get the error

SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = 127.0.0.1, port = 36000

My Server code is as below :

```
class ServerUtilities {
  static Directory _appDirectory;
  static HttpServer _server;
  static File _file;
  ServerUtilities._();

  static ServerUtilities _obj;

  static ServerUtilities instance() {
    if (_obj == null) _obj = ServerUtilities._();
    return _obj;
  }

  Future<Directory> setAppDirectory() async {
    return await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  }

  void initializeServer(String address, int port) async {
    _appDirectory = await setAppDirectory();
    print(_appDirectory.path);
    _file = File('${_appDirectory.path}/sample.txt');
    _file.writeAsString("Hiii ", mode: FileMode.append);

    _server = await HttpServer.bind(address, port);
    print("Server initialized - " + address + ":" + port.toString());
    await for (var req in _server) {
      if (await _file.exists()) {
        print("file exist");
        // req.response.headers.contentType = ContentType.text;
        await _file.openRead().pipe(req.response);
      }
    }
  }

  void stopServer() async {
    await _server.close().catchError(
      (e) {
        print(e);
      },
    ).then(
      (value) => {
        print("Server stopped "),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The server got initialized and everything works fine and can open the provided IP in my mobile browser and it works well but when trying to use Http.get i got the above error.

This is my main.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  ServerUtilities.instance().initializeServer('127.0.0.1', 8010);
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

And this is how I am trying to access, And I am getting the above-specified error.

```
FutureBuilder(
              future: http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8010"),
              builder: (context, data) {
                if (data.hasData)
                  return Text(
                    data.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  );
                else if (data.hasError) {
                  print(data.error);
                  return Text(
                    data.error.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  );
                } else
                  return Text(
                    "No data",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  );
              }),
```

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when the Server is not running. So please check whether `initializeServer` method is working correctly or not.

Comment: it's working correctly I have checked it multiple times by directly putting the address in the chrome(browser) of mobile and its showing correct data. This server is running locally on device. By device, I mean mobile (emulator).

Comment: Are the print statements inside `initializeServer` method running?

Comment: I am only getting the error on flutter app not in browser with the same code its something with how I am accessing the data in the app

Comment: I think your server code is wrong. Check out documentation at https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.1/dart-io/HttpServer-class.html